# printing image on stcker paper vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I would like to print my own labels on label\ sticker paper. I have never done this before and I am unsure on how to repeate a selected image x-amount of times exactly fitting to the stickers on the sticker paper.

How do we do this?

(ussing VB.net)

**EDIT**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
<Canvas Width="100" Height="200">
        <Image Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="Image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/FFR_Hot_Rod_Fenders_9.jpg" />
        <Image Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,12,0,0" Name="Image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/FFR_Hot_Rod_Fenders_9.jpg" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you installed Crystal Reports or Reporting Services within Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi, thanks for our sugestion. I'm not a big fan of 3rd party applications to generate vb.net code. I did however  think of createing an xaml wich I could print. The **Eddit** shows easaly placed images however how can I print the xaml on a 1:1 scale? As you can see I have also been tinkering around with the canvas hoping to find a way to isolate and print it as aposed to the obviously not A4 sized screen